# Unadvertised cold spells mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sense-verbs

> He would not go abroad he had once tried it, but had chanced to strike the Riviera during one of **its carefully unadvertised cold spells**.

The phrase  *its carefully unadvertised cold spells* is a little baffling as to construe it into native language. Does it mean that the Riviera was having cold times that time? But the word **unadvertised** still remains vague in this context.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is long, such as a book, please include a page number or other location also. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Answer (score 5):

The meaning is that the Riviera  has occasional cold spells, and was having one when "he" had visited before. However, those who promote the Riviera are careful not to advertise the existence of such cold spells, indeed to hide them, so that the profitable image of the Riviera as always warm, sunny, and pleasant is not spoiled.